# FIND unique id in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find the unique USER for each ID. The ID must have '3' for a SRC and Null for a date OR if the date is not null then the user with the max date and '3' for a SRC will be needed. I can get each part separate but I'm having a hard time making it work for both of the scenarios below. The table name is MGR. Thanks.

I'd want the results to be:

1. ID = 456 and USER = PSMITH
2. ID = 789 and USER = TREFF

[image]

Comment: OK so what have you tried?  Show your query,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a standard `ROW_NUMBER` query should work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE SRC = 3
)

SELECT ID, USER
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

The reason this works is because `NULL` values sort last with ascending order, or first for descending order.  Since the row number above sorts descending by date, it means that `NULL` dates, if present, would sort first, otherwise the more recent date would appear first.

Comment: You could also specify `NULLS FIRST` in the `ORDER BY` to make it obvious to people not familiar with the default sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the filter in the where clause, with a correlated subquery to pull out the latest id

```
SELECT

FROM 
    mytable t
WHERE 
    t.src = 3
    AND (
        t.date IS NULL
        OR t.date = (
            SELECT MAX(t1.date) FROM mytable t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id AND t1.src = t.src
        )
    )
```